# It is necessary that when the component is removed, it does not just disappear, but leaves behind component with button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

thank you in advance, however, before answering the question, read carefully what I ask for help with all due respect. What i need:

*I need that when the delete button is clicked, the component is not only deleted, but also leaves behind another button, by clicking on which, the remote component is rendered back*

Functionality that already works: rendering a component on click, as well as deleting by a button

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';

import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

interface IParams {
    id: number;
}

interface IBlock {
    deleteBlock(blockToDelete: number) : void
    id: number
}

function App() {

const [newBlock, setNewBlock] = useState([] as IParams[])

const createOnClick = () => {
    const newId =  {
        id: newBlock.length + 1
    }
    setNewBlock([...newBlock, newId])
}

const deleteBlock = (blockToDelete: number) => {
    setNewBlock(
        newBlock.filter((x) => {
            return x.id !== blockToDelete
        })
    )
}

const FunctionalBlock: React.FC<IBlock>  = ({id, deleteBlock}) => {
    return (
        <div style={{display: 'flex', maxWidth: '300px', justifyContent: 'space-between'}}>
            <div>i was created {id} times</div>
            <button onClick={() => {
                deleteBlock(id)
            }}>now delete me</button>
        </div>
    )
}

return (
    <div className="App">
        <button onClick={createOnClick}>
            New block
        </button>
        {
            newBlock.map((x) => (
                <FunctionalBlock id={x.id} key={x.id} deleteBlock={deleteBlock}/>
            ))
        }
    </div>
);
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/silent-sound-0k3sbo?file=/src/index.tsx
here is this code on sandbox!

Comment: use fade animation at first and on setTimeout remove it after animation.

Comment: are you sure you have read my problem before giving an answer?)

Answer (score 1):

Why not just set a state on the block?

```js
const {useState} = React
const FunctionalBlock = ({ id, idx, isDeleted, toggleBlockState }) => {
  return (
    <div
      style={{
        display: "flex",
        maxWidth: "300px",
        justifyContent: "space-between"
      }}
    >
    {
      !isDeleted
      ? <React.Fragment>
        <div>i was created {idx} times</div>
          <button
            onClick={toggleBlockState}
          >
            now delete me
          </button>
        </React.Fragment>
      : <button onClick={toggleBlockState}>REVIVE BLOCK</button>
    }
    </div>
  )
  ;
};

const getNewBlock = (idx) => ({
  id: Date.now(),
  idx,
  isDeleted: false,
})

const toggleIsDeletedById = (id, block) => {
  if (id !== block.id) return block
  return {
    ...block,
    isDeleted: !block.isDeleted
  }
}

const App = () => {
  const [newBlock, setNewBlock] = useState([])
  
  const createOnClick = () => {
    const block = getNewBlock(newBlock.length + 1)
    setNewBlock([...newBlock, block])
  }
  
  const toggleBlockStateById = (id) => {
    setNewBlock(newBlock.map((block) => toggleIsDeletedById(id, block)))
  }
  
  return (
    <div>
      <div>NEW BLOCK</div>
      <div><button onClick={createOnClick}>ADD NEW BLOCK +</button></div>
      <div>
        {
          newBlock.map(block => <FunctionalBlock {...block} toggleBlockState={() => toggleBlockStateById(block.id)}/>)
        }
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much and sorry for stupid question!

Comment: @ArakeloveYury question is/was not stupid - sometimes you want a certain logic to work so bad, that you miss an idea that is much simpler :)